# Add a subtitle to plot.xts

Tags: r, plot, xts, subtitle

Is there a way to add a subtitle like in base plot to plot.xts?

```
plot(xts(rnorm(100), order.by = as.Date(1:100)), sub = "Subtitle")
plot(rnorm(100), sub = "Subtitle", type = "l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can use plot.zoo on an xts object and get the subtitle (and x label for that matter) to show up at the bottom of the plot. From my experimentations it seems to be a problem with the date label and margin setting in the plot.xts default clipping off the x label and subtitle (which by default show at the bottom of the plot).

I was taking a class from DataCamp regarding time series visualization and the content shown here

https://rpubs.com/odenipinedo/visualizing-time-series-data-in-R

Seems to demonstrate successful subtitle display in the example plots, but I was not able to reproduce it when going through their code exercises for the class, though my code was deemed correct by the autograder of the class… I am trying to contact the instructor of the class, Arnaud Amsellem, to ask about it. Sorry for not able to provide a better solution…

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35615489)